# Parsing Json Data string And Retrieve Element

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My json is

```
 string aaaa = "{\"respCode\":\"1\",\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"response\":{\"chId\":1,\"refId\":\"YBL4ABC0D3D61A349F18605928DD63E8886\",\"approvalRefNum\":\"264992511\",\"responseCode\":\"000\",\"responseReason\":\"Successful\",\"complianceReason\":\"\",\"complianceRespCd\":\"\",\"billDetails\":\"[{\"name\":\"Consumer Number\",\"value\":\"900001073788\"}]\",\"billerResponse\":\"{\"customerName\":\"MNTALI\",\"amount\":\"421\",\"dueDate\":\"2021-11-06\",\"custConvFee\":\"\",\"custConvDesc\":\"\",\"billDate\":\"2021-10-16\",\"billNumber\":\"9337718556142\",\"billPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"billTags\":[{\"name\":\"Early Payment Amount\",\"value\":\"41200\"}]}\",\"additionalInfo\":\"[{\"name\":\"Early Payment Date\",\"value\":\"2021-10-23\"},{\"name\":\"URL\",\"value\":\"https://cp.tatapower.com:4443/inv?inv_nou003dMDkzMzc3MTg2MTQy\"}]\"}}";
```

I want to retrieve the value of customerName.

When I tried something like this to parse my JSON string

```
  var userObj1 = JObject.Parse(aaaa);
```

I am getting Error such as:

> 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: n. Path 'response.billDetails', line 1, position 244.'

Comment: That is an invalid JSON, it has excess double quotes around `billDetails` and `additionalInfo` arrays and around `billerResponse` object value.

Comment: For future problems like this: Take your json string (and replace the \" with ") and paste it in a json validator like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid json. Need to remove extra quotes at first

```
var json=aaaa.Replace("\"[","[").Replace("]\"","]").Replace("\"{","{").Replace("}\"","}");

var userObj1 = JObject.Parse(json);
```

output

```
{
  "respCode": "1",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "response": {
    "chId": 1,
    "refId": "YBL4ABC0D3D61A349F18605928DD63E8886",
    "approvalRefNum": "264992511",
    "responseCode": "000",
    "responseReason": "Successful",
    "complianceReason": "",
    "complianceRespCd": "",
    "billDetails": [
      {
        "name": "Consumer Number",
        "value": "900001073788"
      }
    ],
    "billerResponse": {
      "customerName": "MNTALI",
      "amount": "421",
      "dueDate": "2021-11-06",
      "custConvFee": "",
      "custConvDesc": "",
      "billDate": "2021-10-16",
      "billNumber": "9337718556142",
      "billPeriod": "MONTHLY",
      "billTags": [
        {
          "name": "Early Payment Amount",
          "value": "41200"
        }
      ]
    },
    "additionalInfo": [
      {
        "name": "Early Payment Date",
        "value": "2021-10-23"
      },
      {
        "name": "URL",
        "value": "https://cp.tatapower.com:4443/inv?inv_nou003dMDkzMzc3MTg2MTQy"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its invalid JSON, remove " from before and after of '{','[','}',']'

```
string aaaa = 
              "{" +
                "\"respCode\":\"1\",\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"response\":" +
                "{" +
                "\"chId\":1,\"refId\":\"YBL4ABC0D3D61A349F18605928DD63E8886\",\"approvalRefNum\":\"264992511\",\"responseCode\":\"000\",\"responseReason\":\"Successful\",\"complianceReason\":\"\",\"complianceRespCd\":\"\",\"billDetails\":" +
                    "[" +
                        "{\"name\":\"Consumer Number\",\"value\":\"900001073788\"}" +
                    "]," +
                    "\"billerResponse\":" +
                        "{" +
                            "\"customerName\":\"MNTALI\",\"amount\":\"421\",\"dueDate\":\"2021-11-06\",\"custConvFee\":\"\",\"custConvDesc\":\"\",\"billDate\":\"2021-10-16\",\"billNumber\":\"9337718556142\",\"billPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"billTags\":" +
                            "[" +
                                "{\"name\":\"Early Payment Amount\",\"value\":\"41200\"}" +
                            "]" +
                        "}" +
                    ",\"additionalInfo\":" +
                    "[" +
                        "{\"name\":\"Early Payment Date\",\"value\":\"2021-10-23\"}," +
                        "{\"name\":\"URL\",\"value\":\"https://cp.tatapower.com:4443/inv?inv_nou003dMDkzMzc3MTg2MTQy\"}" +
                    "]" +
                  "}" +
                "}";

var userObj1 = JObject.Parse(aaaa);
```

its work for me